# Update char count when closing/opening modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twig

Some context: I have a page where you can add text to labels; if you click the label a modal opens and you have `textareas` to type and below that, there's a char counter.

Problem: if you insert text in the first label, when you open the second label modal, the char counter has the last count registered. It only resets when you click inside the `textarea`.

The modal `twig` it's a simple bootstrap template with a close button and cancel/submit buttons in the bottom with `countdown maxlength="80"` in the 
`input`.

this is the counter js:

```
define(function() {
    'use strict';

    return ['$compile', '$timeout', function CountdownDirective($compile, $timeout) {
        return {
            scope: {},
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                var limit = attrs.maxlength;
                var span = $compile('<span class="countdown" ng-class="countdown.status">{{ charsLeft }}</span>')(scope);

                scope.charsLeft = attrs.maxlength;
                element.after(span);

                function limitCheck(event) {
                    var length = element.val().length;
                    var code = event.keyCode;

                    if (length < limit) {
                        return;
                    }

                    switch (code) {
                        case 8: // allow delete
                        case 9:
                        case 17:
                        case 36: // and cursor keys
                        case 35:
                        case 37:
                        case 38:
                        case 39:
                        case 40:
                        case 46:
                        case 65:
                            return;
                    }
                }

                var updateCount = function() {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        var length = element.val().length;
                        var diff = limit - length;
                        var status = 'text-success';

                        scope.charsLeft = diff || 0;

                        if (scope.charsLeft < attrs.maxlength * 0.3) {
                            status = 'text-warning';
                        }

                        if (scope.charsLeft < attrs.maxlength * 0.1) {
                            status = 'text-danger';
                        }

                        scope.countdown = {
                            status: status
                        };

                        // Truncate
                        if (diff < 0) {
                            element.val(element.val().substr(0, limit));

                            updateCount();
                        }
                    }, 0);
                };

                element.focus(updateCount).change(updateCount);
                element.keyup(updateCount).change(updateCount);
                element.keydown(limitCheck);

                updateCount();
            }
        };
    }];
});
```

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is to hook into a callback upon opening the modal. Is that available at all?

Comment: there's a callback when the modal get closed?

Comment: there's a `data-dismiss="modal"` in the close button if that's helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually found how to do it by focusing the `input`every time the `modal` opens :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modal').on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
     $('.form-control').focus();
});
```

being `modal` the modal class and `form-control`the input class.